# Vue. How to get a value of a "key" attribute in created element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to create a component and get its `:key` for using in axios.

The element is created, but I can't get a key. It's undefined.

```html
    <div class="container" id="root">
        <paddock is="paddock-item" v-for="paddock in paddocks" :key="paddock.key" class="paddock">
        </paddock>
    </div>
    <script>
    var pItem = {
        props: ['key'],
        template: '<div :test="key"></div>',
        created: function() {
            console.log(key);
        }
        };
    new Vue({
        el: '#root',
        components: {
            'paddock-item': pItem
        },
        data: {
            paddocks: [
                {key: 1},
                {key: 2},
                {key: 3},
                {key: 4}
            ]
        }
    })
    </script>
```

I tried some variants, but no result. `key` was empty.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Vue 3 you can get the key with:

```js
import { getCurrentInstance} from "vue";

getCurrentInstance().vnode.key
```

Comment: it helped a lot.

Comment: best solution for vue3

Comment: what is the difference with using `this.$.vnode.key`?

Answer (score 98):

you don't need to use an extra attribute. You can get the key by

```
this.$vnode.key
```

Comment: THANK you.  How convenient that this was just posted as an answer.

Comment: Has this changed in Vue3? When I attempt to access `this.$vnode.key` I get "undefined". Passing the same value to a prop of `id`, I know that the value is not "undefined" because I do get my `item.id` value.

Comment: In Vue 3 you can get the key by `this.$.vnode.key`

Comment: does not works on vue3

Answer (score 7):

This answer answers the question of how you would *pass* the key to a child component. If you just want to get the current key from inside the child component, use the highest voted answer.

---

`key` is a [special attribute][1] in Vue. You will have to call your property something else.

Here is an alternative using `pkey` instead.

```js
console.clear()
var pItem = {
  props: ['pkey'],
  template: '<div :test="pkey"></div>',
  created: function() {
    console.log(this.pkey);
  }
};
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  components: {
    'paddock-item': pItem
  },
  data: {
    paddocks: [{
        key: 1
      },
      {
        key: 2
      },
      {
        key: 3
      },
      {
        key: 4
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="root">
  <paddock-item v-for="paddock in paddocks" :pkey="paddock.key" :key="paddock.key" class="paddock">
  </paddock-item>
</div>
```

Comment: By doing this, you effectively duplicate the same value in 2 props every single time you use the `v-for` directive. How do you simplify this so that I'm not writing `:key="item.id" :id="item.id"` every single time I use the `v-for` directive? I can't bring `key` in as a prop, which would IMHO be the easiest and most logical answer. So how do I eliminate this redundancy. There surely MUST be a way... (before you say use `this.$vnode.key`, I don't think it works in Vue3 because it's not working for me. I get a value of `undefined`.

Comment: I was a bit annoyed by this "duplication" as well. But in this case the "duplication" is an illusion. It just feels like you should get "id" for free since you're already passing the same value into key. But providing a value for :key is not the same thing as passing a prop to a component.
:key (as others have already pointed out) serves a separate internal purpose. Think of it as something you are passing  to Vue itself.  it just so happens that in most cases, since it must be unique, it usually has the same value as the id  prop we set when rendering a list of components using v-for

Answer (score 2):

In Vue 3 you can get the key by

```
this.$.vnode.key
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **this.$options._parentVnode.key** work for me:

```
created() {
   console.log(this.$options._parentVnode.key)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

Object.keys(data.value)

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain why this should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Using Vue extension for chrome you can see the keys in the elements tree:

[image: Vue keys]

Here is the link to extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd