# How do I get v-for key in component's event?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I Have a costumer component with `v-for` like below :

```
<my-component
  v-for="(item,index) in filteredList"
  :key="item.Rd"
  :item="item"
>
```

Inside my-component

```
<template>
    <div 
        @click="findSomething($event)"
    >
    ...HTML
    </div>
</template>
```

I try a lot way to pass key props into `my-comonent` but all of it don't working
If I designed `props:['key']` that got errors
`"key" is a reserved attribute and cannot be used as component prop.` then I still can't got key
I rely need the value of key become it can be identify which item I trigger in event

Comment: You define key yourself, so just pass in as a property whatever you have set key to be? In this case "item.Rd"

Answer (score 2):

The error you are receiving is self-explanatory. You cannot specify it as `key` in your props because that is reserved by Vue.

There are 2 ways of fixing this, both are detailed in this answer: [Vue. How to get a value of a "key" attribute in created element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45852026/vue-how-to-get-a-value-of-a-key-attribute-in-created-element/51089128)

The first way is simply by renaming the prop that you are passing in, the user in the above post used `pkey` instead of `key`

The second solution is using `this.$vnode.key` inside of your component to access the key you are using.

Comment: I try this one ```this.$vnode.key``` but got undefined

Comment: @JinLin Did you put that in the child or the parent? If that is giving you trouble, I would recommend just creating a separately named variable and storing the key value inside to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You actually explain the problem, you can not name the props as 'key' instead how about with other name ?

But, you are passing the whole item as a prop in your example also, so you can get the key from there.

Comment: I kwon that but  I don't wanna attach to an other attribute some like ```data-rd``` in each component , to my way of thinking , the ```:key``` prop was already assign in the component why can i just get it

Comment: Oh I see, with `:key`  the component actually have not receiving that value because `v-bin:key` or `:key` is used by vue to mannagin the state in list rendering, so you have to declare an other property in order to receive the key. Look at the documentation : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State

Answer (score 0):

"key" is a reserved attribute and cannot be used as component prop.

Try using it like this.

```js
Vue.component('mycomponent', props:['keyval'], template:myform)
```

Pass `:keyval='indx'` as component attribute.

Just get this prop using this in any of the methods bening used inside the component.

```js
methods:{onformchange():{console.log(this.keyval)}}
```